# JSF Project in Eclipse with Maven gives ClassNotFoundException for FacesServlet

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, maven

I've created a Maven project in Eclipse. From "project facets" menu I selected Dynamic Web Module, Java and Java Server Faces. Added some dependencies from pom.xml successfully like jsf-api and servlet-api. Then I wrote a simple Java bean and an xhtml page that uses the bean.

When I build war file with "maven clean install" and deploy it to Tomcat manually, it works as expected. But when I select "Run on Server" from Eclipse it gives the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /testjsf1 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It seems jsf libraries are not linked as expected when it is run from Eclipse. Do you have any idea about the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: This solved my problem(Actually we are adding the maven downloaded jars to the lib folder by these steps which is added in build path automatically by maven but for lib maven doesn't does it)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In "Project Properties" -> "Deployment Assembly", adding "Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies" solves the problem!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. With this solution, I got much more ClassNotFoundExceptions.

Comment: That's works fine, thanks !

Comment: The idea is that the jars must be in the folder WEB-INF/lib