# Classpath entry org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result

Tags: maven, jsf-2.2, eclipse-luna, m2e-wtp

I created a web project inspired by [jsf-blank.zip](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/code/jsf-blank.zip) from [JSF 2 with Facelets, Ajax, and PrimeFaces](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Getting-Started). After a few days of progress  (and solving numerous issues, thanks to the SO community, mainly) with my site I'm stuck at:

*HTTP 404 - The requested resource is not available* in Eclipse's internal browser and FF.

Eclipse's console shows:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
```

That's only fair and I had that before (one of the *numerous issues* mentioned above) but I can't convince it to leave this time.

---

**EDIT:**

[mostar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774142/1744774) did the trick. **BUT**, this setting is removed with every new *Maven* → *Update Project...*

---

Furthermore, there are the following warnings and errors I couldn't get rid off (permanently) no matter how many SO and other web  pages I consulted:

- [image] *Classpath entry* org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER *will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.*

  I found how to get rid of this (see above) but with every *Maven* → *Update Project...* it's there again.
- [image] *Implementation of project facet jboss.m2 could not be found. Functionality will be limited.*
- [image] *Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0.*
- [image] *One or more constraints have not been satisfied.* [Which one? The one immediately above?]

Who's the culprit for all this?